# % unit in MS Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

The following code is for an image meant to fill 80% of the browser height:

```
<div style="max-height:80vh;"><img src="(img url)" style="max-
height:100%;"></div>
```

The image displays perfectly fine in all browsers except for Edge, which seems to completely ignore the CSS.  Using "view source", the browser has calculated 80vw to 546.4px, which is correct.  It displays the div at the correct height, but makes the img 853px tall (extending below the bottom of the div), even though it also claims that it has calculated the 100% to 546.4px!  What's going on?

Comment: This doesn't work in firefox, and in chrome, too, btw...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're specifying a `max-height` value for your parent div. Switch the div to just `height`. Now the 100% has something to work off of.

Comment: Thank you, that does work, but I had the max-height in the div there for other reasons.  Isn't there is some way to do both?

Comment: I'm sure you can still set a max height but you'll need the height value as well